# When caching response what would be a reasonable value for maxage header when response does not change?

Tags: yql

I have a YQL query that returns data that I know for sure will not ever change.
In order to avoid rate limits, I was thinking of adding a maxage header to the yql response.

Now I'm wondering what a reasonable value would be (in the case where I know for certain that the response will never ever change): a year ? 10 years ? more ?

Are there any specificities as to the way yql would treat the maxage header ?

Answer (score 1):

Nice article on maxAge and how to use it: http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/ . This should answer most of your queries about max age.

For your second question, if the response will never ever change, why even make an API call in the first place? You could eliminate the network latency altogether and have a conf/property file having the response on your server itself.

Am not quite sure if I understood what you meant by if there were any specifications to the way YQL would treat the header but will try to answer it to best of my knowledge. From the link I shared earlier, following are a few lines:

> Secondly you can just ask YQL to cache the response to a statement for longer – just append the _maxage query parameter to your call and the result will be stored in cache for that length of time (but not shorter than it would have been originally):
>
> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where location=90210&_maxage=3600
>
> This is really useful when you’re using output from a table that’s not caching enough or an XML source without having to do any open table work

Hope this helps.